# Does ServiceStack.Text has any Json Serializer/DeSerializer size limit?

Tags: json, serialization, servicestack, deserialization, servicestack-text

Does Service-stack.Text has any Json Serialize/ DeSerialize size limit ?

I want to know is there any size limit on Json serialization and DeSerialization. Based on this I want to send no of object collection as input.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no built-in limit in [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) of how large a C# object to serialize or JSON string to deserialize. It just takes longer and use more memory the larger the object size/payload is.

Comment: @sudheerreddy No its very use-case dependent. Feel free to measure the results yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Let me check.